# Don't trigger #main mouseenter when doing mouseenter on #main-child-element

Tags: javascript

I have a `mouseenter` event on my `#main` div:

```
main.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    console.log("mouseenter main");
    textElement.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Within `#main` I have a child `#element` also attached to a `mouseenter` event:

```
element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    console.log("mouseenter on element but dont trigger main mouseenter");
});
```

**How do I `mouseenter` on `#element` without triggering the `mouseenter` event from `#main`?** Currently when hovering #element both mouseenter event are triggered.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/md3jmxeL/

As example im showing a blue box upon `mouseenter` on `#main` - I don't want to trigger/show this blue box when doing `mouseenter` on `#element`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mouseover` event handler, adjusted example here: http://jsfiddle.net/md3jmxeL/2/

```
main.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    console.log("mouseenter main");
    textElement.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Just change all mouseenter to mouseover. These events differ only in case of event bubbling - that's your case. Read more about it here: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseover-and-mouseenter-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

A [mouseenter event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) gets sent to each element in the hierarchy, which is different from mouseover which has one event that travels up the hierarchy.

Because of this you cannot stopPropagation on the child mouseenter event because the event doesn't bubble as each element gets their own event call.

You could use mouseover and stopPropagation within the child's event:

```
main.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) { /*...*/ });

element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    /*...*/
});
```

But with that you are going to get a mouseover event each time the user moves back and fourth from the parent to child elements.

Probably the better choice is to use one event on the parent element and check the event.target to see which element triggered the event. If it is your child element then do your work

```
main.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    if(event.target == document.getElementById("element")){
        //do work
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is if you need to add event listeners for `mouseenter` (and it will also work with `mouseover`) and effectively mask a child element for a given event.

**Approach:** In the outer `mouseenter` event listener, find all the elements the mouse is currently over with `document.querySelectorAll(":hover")`. If one if these elements has an `id` which matches the masking child's `id`, return and do not process the parent `mouseenter` logic further. If the child has attached an event listener for the same event, it will still be triggered.

**Example:**

```
main.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {

    // Child element masking code block    
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll( ":hover" );
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        // Prevent parent event logic from executing if on specified child
        if(elems[i].id === "element") {
            return;
        }
    }

    // The rest of your code
    console.log("mouseenter main");
    textElement.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bxc9t961/1/)